# GWTP get access from child presenter/view to parent presenter/view

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I have 2 presenters/view. Lets call them `parent` and `child`. `parent` presenter is a container (using slot mechanism) for the `child` presenter.
In the `child` presenter's view user clicked button and I would like to handle this action in `parent` presenter.

How can I do this? What is the best approach? Should I use some kind of event and eventhandler? Or should I inject one presenter to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are possible.

**For events - GWTP have a simplified version of GWT events:**

```
public interface MyEventHandler extends EventHandler {
    void onMyEvent(MyEvent event);
}

public class MyEvent extends GwtEvent<MyEventHandler> {
    public static Type<MyEventHandler> TYPE = new Type<MyEventHandler>();
    private Object myData;
    public Type<MyEventHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        return TYPE;
    }
    protected void dispatch(MyEventHandler handler) {
        handler.onMyEvent(this);
    }

    public MyEvent(Object myData) {
        this.myData = myData;
    }
    /*The cool thing*/
    public static void fire(HasHandlers source, Object myData){
        source.fireEvent(new MyEvent(myData));
    }
}
```

So in your child presenter you'll simply do:

```
MyEvent.fire(this, thatObjectYoudLikeToPass);
```

and to register it, in the parent, you'd either use:

```
addRegisteredHandler(MyEvent.TYPE, handler);
```

or

```
addVisibleHandler(MyEvent.TYPE, handler);
```

if you want it to be processed only when the parent is visible. I suggest you yo add these handlers in onBind method of your presenter (don't forget to call super.onBind() first when overriding)

**For injection:** 
Simply make sure:

1. Your parent presenter is a singleton
2. To avoid circular dependency error in GIN do not wire it like

   @Inject ParentPresenter presenter;

instead do it like this:

```
@Inject 
Provider<ParentPresenter> presenterProvider;
```

and access it with `presenterProvider.get()` in your child

Comment: How to make sure that Parent presenter is singleton? I am binding it this way: `bindPresenter(AppPresenter.class, AppPresenter.MyView.class, AppView.class, AppPresenter.MyProxy.class);` I can bind as a singleton only widget. I also have in configuration: `bind(AppView.Binder.class).in(Singleton.class);`- but this is only a view. Can You help?

Comment: Presenters are Singleton by default.